# Improve detecting words like "she" and "her" from sentences and return "Female" as a result

Tags: r, if-statement, nlp

I have a variable "bio_sentences" and as the name of the variable suggests, it has four to five bio sentences of individuals (extracted and split into sentences from "bio" variable). I am trying to determine what gender an individual is using this logic...

```
Femalew <- c("She", "Her")
Check <- str_extract_all(bio,Femalew)
Check <- Check[Check != "character(0)"]
Gender <- vector("character")
if(length(Check) > 0){
  Gender[1] <- "Female"
}else{
  Gender[1] <- "Male"
}
for(i in 1:length(bio_sentences)){
  Gender[i] <- Gender[1]
}
```

I am getting a good result (majority in my dataset are male), however there are few misses (some females aren't detected) despite the fact the sentences have "she" or "her" in them. Is there anyway, I can improve the accuracy of the logic or deploy some new function like grepl?

EDIT:

```
    data1.Gender    A B C D E   data1.Description
1   Female  0   0   0   0   0   Ranjit Singh President of Boparan Holdings Limited Ranjit is President of Boparan Holdings Limited.
2   Female  0   0   0   NA  NA  He founded the business in 1993 and has more than 25 years’ experience in the food industry.
3   Female  0   0   0   NA  NA  Ranjit is particularly skilled at growing businesses, both organically and through acquisition.
4   Female  0   0   0   NA  NA  Notable acquisitions include Northern Foods and Brookes Avana in 2011.
5   Female  0   0   0   NA  NA  Ranjit and his wife Baljinder Boparan are the sole shareholders of Boparan Holdings, the holding company for 2 Sisters Food Group.
6   Female  0   0   0   NA  NA  s
```

The above is a person from the data, My requirement is that the code reads all the lines in the "data1.description" (in my code this is in a for loop, so it reads all sentences for each individual) and as you can see the person is Male and there is clearly a "He" in one of the sentences, however I get it as "Female" by applying the above logic I have written before.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you add some data to make your code working? You can `dput(bio_sentences)` if you can post your data, or create some fake data whom make your code working with the issues.

Comment: Done. Please have a look.

Comment: Some simple things you could do to make your approach more effective: (a) make everything lower case (input strings and male/female patterns), (b) use `\\b` as a regex word boundary and make your patterns, e.g., `"\\bhe\\b"` and  `"\\bshe\\b"`, that way words that include matching substrings won't count (like *Northern* contains *her*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by @Merijn van Tilborg, you should have very clear in your mind your sentences, because if there is more than one pronoun, your work could not give the desired outputs.
However you can manage also those cases, we can try with a the `dplyr` and `tidytext` packages, but we have to clean up the data a bit:

```
# explicit the genders
female <- c("She", "Her")
male <- c("He", "His")

# here your data, with several examples of cases
df <- data.frame(
line = c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
text = c("She is happy",            # female
         "Her dog is happy",        # female (if we look at the subject, it's not female..)
         "He is happy",             # male
         "His dog is happy",        # male
         "It is happy",             # ?
         "She and he are happy"),   # both!
         stringsAsFactors = FALSE ) # life saver
```

Now we can try something like this:

```
library(tidytext)
library(dplyr)

  df %>%
  unnest_tokens(word, text) %>%                                            # put words in rows
  mutate(gender = ifelse(word %in% tolower(female),'female',
                  ifelse(word %in% tolower(male), 'male','unknown'))) %>%  # detect male and female, remember tolower!
  filter(gender!='unknown') %>%                                            # remove the unknown
  right_join(df) %>%                                                       # join with the original sentences keeping all of them
  select(-word)                                                            # remove useless column

  line gender                 text
1    1 female         She is happy
2    2 female     Her dog is happy
3    3   male          He is happy
4    4   male     His dog is happy
5    5   <NA>          It is happy
6    6 female She and he are happy
7    6   male She and he are happy
```

And you can see the 1,2,3,4 sentences are ok with your standard, "it" is not defined, and if there are male and female, we double the row, and let you understand why.

Lastly, you can collapse in one row adding to the `dplyr` chain this:

```
%>% group_by(text, line) %>% summarise(gender = paste(gender, collapse = ','))

# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   text [?]
  text                  line gender     
  <chr>                <dbl> <chr>      
1 He is happy              3 male       
2 Her dog is happy         2 female     
3 His dog is happy         4 male       
4 It is happy              5 NA         
5 She and he are happy     6 female,male
6 She is happy             1 female
```

---

*EDIT*:
Let's try with your data:

```
data1 <- read.table(text="
    data1.Gender    A B C D E   data1.Description
1   Female  0   0   0   0   0   'Ranjit Singh President of Boparan Holdings Limited Ranjit is President of Boparan Holdings Limited.'
2   Female  0   0   0   NA  NA  'He founded the business in 1993 and has more than 25 years’ experience in the food industry.'
3   Female  0   0   0   NA  NA  'Ranjit is particularly skilled at growing businesses, both organically and through acquisition.'
4   Female  0   0   0   NA  NA  'Notable acquisitions include Northern Foods and Brookes Avana in 2011.'
5   Female  0   0   0   NA  NA  'Ranjit and his wife Baljinder Boparan are the sole shareholders of Boparan Holdings, the holding company for 2 Sisters Food Group.'
6   Female  0   0   0   NA  NA  's'",stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


# explicit the genders, in this case I've put also the names
female <- c("She", "Her","Baljinder")
male <- c("He", "His","Ranjit")

# clean the data
df <- data.frame(
line = rownames(data1),
text = data1$data1.Description,
stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(tidytext)
library(dplyr)

  df %>%
  unnest_tokens(word, text) %>%                                            # put words in rows
  mutate(gender = ifelse(word %in% tolower(female),'female',
                  ifelse(word %in% tolower(male), 'male','unknown'))) %>%  # detect male and female, remember tolower!
  filter(gender!='unknown') %>%                                            # remove the unknown
  right_join(df) %>%                                                       # join with the original sentences keeping all of them
  select(-word) %>% 
  group_by(text, line) %>%
  summarise(gender = paste(gender, collapse = ','))
```

As result:

```
Joining, by = "line"
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   text [?]
  text                                                            line  gender       
  <chr>                                                           <chr> <chr>        
1 He founded the business in 1993 and has more than 25 years’ ex~ 2     male         
2 Notable acquisitions include Northern Foods and Brookes Avana ~ 4     NA           
3 Ranjit and his wife Baljinder Boparan are the sole shareholder~ 5     male,male,fe~
4 Ranjit is particularly skilled at growing businesses, both org~ 3     male         
5 Ranjit Singh President of Boparan Holdings Limited Ranjit is P~ 1     male,male    
6 s                                                               6     NA
```

The real game is to define all the words you can think as "male" or "female".

Comment: I have just edited the question, can you have a look... Thanks

Comment: @MohammedSarfarazuddin , edited the answer, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

This is far more complex as context is key here. Take a look at the three phrases below...

Susan had a great Professor and HIS name was Adam. HE taught HIS favorite student all there is to know...
(Susan is not detected as female but as male)

Susan had a great Professor and HIS name was Adam. HE taught HER all there is to know...
(OK, we have a SHE now but also a HE)

Susan had a great Professor named Adam. Adam taught HER all there is to know...
(OK, we have a SHE)

Comment: You are right, but maybe OP has those data and need a kind of solution (+1 however).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer already given, I also strongly suggest also to add the most common female names into that list. They can be easily found online as the top 100 most popular female names in a country for example. I am sure even if you add about 500 top occurring names to that female list you get quite a decent start, and do the same for the males.

Furthermore I give you an example with a bit of decision making rules. How likely is it to be female or male. One approach might be just count the occurrences and calculate a ratio. Based on the ratio you can make your own decisions. My choices are just an arbitrary example and put as one line per decision (can be coded far more efficient).

```
library(data.table) ## just my personal preference above dplyr
library(stringr) ## just my personal favorite when I deal with strings

df = data.table(text = c("Because Sandra is a female name and we talk a few times about her, she is most likely a female he says.",
       "Sandra is mentioned and the only references are about how she did everything to achieve her goals.", 
       "Nothing is mentioned that reveals a gender.",
       "She talks about him and he talks about her.",
       "Sandra says: he is nice and she is nice too.",
       "Adam is a male and we only talk about him")))

f.indicators = c("she", "her", "susan", "sandra")
m.indicators = c("he", "him", "his", "steve", "adam")

df[, f.count := sum(str_split(str_to_lower(text), "[[:space:]]|[[:punct:]]")[[1]] %in% f.indicators, na.rm = TRUE), by = text]
df[, m.count := sum(str_split(str_to_lower(text), "[[:space:]]|[[:punct:]]")[[1]] %in% m.indicators, na.rm = TRUE), by = text]
df[f.count != 0 | m.count != 0, gender_ratio_female := f.count / (f.count + m.count)]
df[, decision := "Unknown"]
df[gender_ratio_female == 1, decision := "Female, no male indications"]
df[gender_ratio_female == 0, decision := "Male, no female indicators"]
df[gender_ratio_female > 0.4 & gender_ratio_female < 0.6, decision := "Gender should be checked"]
df[gender_ratio_female > 0.6 & gender_ratio_female < 1, decision := "Probably a Female"]
df[gender_ratio_female > 0 & gender_ratio_female < 0.4, decision := "Probably a Male"]
```

P.S. Sorry I am struggling to get the output table formatted here, I am new here

```
                                                                       text f.count m.count   gender_ratio_female                    decision
1: Because Sandra is a female name and we talk a few times about her, she is most likely a female he says.       3       1              0.7500           Probably a Female
2:      Sandra is mentioned and the only references are about how she did everything to achieve her goals.       3       0              1.0000 Female, no male indications
3:                                                             Nothing is mentioned that reveals a gender.       0       0                  NA                     Unknown
4:                                                             She talks about him and he talks about her.       2       2              0.5000    Gender should be checked
5:                                                            Sandra says: he is nice and she is nice too.       2       1              0.6667           Probably a Female
6:                                                               Adam is a male and we only talk about him       0       2              0.0000  Male, no female indicators
```